# Good book or reference to learn Kalman Filter

Tags: kalman-filters, statistics, linear-algebra

I am totally new to the Kalman filter. I've had some basic courses on conditional probability and linear algebra. Can someone suggest a good book or any resource on the web which can help me can understand Kalman Filter operation?

Most websites start directly with the formula and what they mean, but I am more interested in its derivation, or if not detail derivation then at least the physical significance of each operation and parameter.

Comment: take a look at this question: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/2066/1273

Comment: [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CaCcOwJPytQ) there is a very helpful series of 55 short lectures, starting from scratch

Comment: A highly cited paper, it will give you a practical understanding on this topic [click here](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~rmf25/papers/Understanding%20the%20Basis%20of%20the%20Kalman%20Filter.pdf)

Answer (score 17):

Many years ago I wrote the tutorial [N. A. Thacker, A. J. Lacey - The Likelihood Interpretation of the Kalman Filter](https://web.archive.org/web/20190713124725/http://www.tina-vision.net/docs/memos/1996-002.pdf) (Also [on CiteSeerX](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.599.7601)) on the Kalman filter.  It derives the filter using both the conventional matrix approach as well as showing it's statistical assumptions as an 'optimal' least squares filter.

Comment: It was you!!! = ) Fantastic tutorial, I really enjoyed reading it sometime last year. Welcome to DSP.SE!!!

Comment: This is a great tutorial. Do you think you could update it if you have any new thoughts about Kalman filter? Thank You.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a nice write-up of the Kalman filter: [Bilgin Esm - Kalman Filter For Dummies](http://bilgin.esme.org/BitsBytes/KalmanFilterforDummies.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for a book as well, best to cover the basics required to learn and implement kalman filtering in real life situation. So far I finalized my choice to this:

[Fundamentals of Kalman Filtering: A Practical Approach (Progress in Astronautics and Aeronautics) by Paul Zarchan](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1600867189)

I think this should be the one and I'm ordering it now. :)

Answer (score 1):

A good 3 part series of Youtube Videos (~10 mins each) provides an intuitive understanding of the Kalman Filter.

[Student Dave - Tutorial: Kalman Filter with MATLAB](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FkCT_LV9Syk) (YouTube Video).

One thing to note is that there are various ways to derive the Kalman Filter equations and each method gives you a different perspective of how it works. So, I suggest that you look into 2 - 3 different derivations to help you internalize this algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

A Very good book to learn [Kalman Theory and implementation using MATLAB is here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470173661)

Answer (score 1):

Recently, Mandic, Danilo P. and Kanna, Sithan and Constantinides, Anthony G. published "[On the Intrinsic Relationship Between the Least Mean Square and Kalman Filters](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/MSP.2015.2461733)" in IEEE Signal processing magazine:

> The Kalman filter and the least mean square (LMS) adaptive filter are
>   two of the most popular adaptive estimation algorithms that are often
>   used interchangeably in a number of statistical signal processing
>   applications. They are typically treated as separate entities, with
>   the former as a realization of the optimal Bayesian estimator and the
>   latter as a recursive solution to the optimal Wiener filtering
>   problem. In this lecture note, we consider a system identification
>   framework within which we develop a joint perspective on Kalman
>   filtering and LMS-type algorithms, achieved through analyzing the
>   degrees of freedom necessary for optimal stochastic gradient descent
>   adaptation. This approach permits the introduction of Kalman filters
>   without any notion of Bayesian statistics, which may be beneficial for
>   many communities that do not rely on Bayesian methods.

Answer (score 1):

A good book that I’ve personally used is [*Optimal Filtering* by Brian D.O. Anderson and John B. Moore](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486439380). The entire book is dedicated to a precise explanation of the discrete-time Kalman filter and its extensions.

Answer (score 0):

The best resource is Wikipedia page in my opinion. Here is a minimal and simple implementation of Kalman Filter with same notations given in Wikipedia page: https://github.com/zziz/kalman-filter