# Incorporating delayed data in Kalman filter

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, kalman-filters, estimation

my guide has told me to get familiarized with state estimates and kalman filter ....the problem is that:

1) I am totally new to this topic and finding it really difficult to understand due to lack of materials. so, can someone give some suggestions on how to proceed.

2) I am also suppose to incorporate delayed data into kalman filter equations. help is needed on this aspect also

all these have to be implemented on MATLAB..

Comment: [Related](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/2066/1273). You have nice info and links on Kalman filters there.